# Merging a list of vectors with a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, lapply

I have a list of dataframes `lsD` and a list of vectors `lsV`. The length of the vectors is identical to the numbers of rows in the dataframes (in the toy example = 5).

I would like to add the vectors as an additional column to each dataframe. I got it to work with a `for` loop, but my general question is: how can iterate through two lists by name without `for`? Is there a `lapply` way to do this?

Here is a toy example and my solution using the `for` loop:

```
lsV <- list(x = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5,replace=T), 
            y = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5, replace=T), 
            z=sample(LETTERS[1:5], 5, replace=T))

lsD <- list(x = data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20,replace=T), ncol=4)), 
        y = data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20,replace=T), ncol=4)),
        z =  data.frame(matrix(sample(LETTERS[1:5], 20,replace=T), ncol=4)))

for (i in 1:length(lsV)) {lsD[[i]]<-cbind(lsD[[i]], lsV[[i]])}
```

Any ideas? I tried with the following, but of course it didn't work. Thanks!

```
lapply(names(lsD), function(X) {lsD$X<-cbind(lsD$X, lsV$X)})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Map` function would be useful here

```
 Map(cbind, lsD, Z=lsV)
```

Both `Map` and `mapply` are apply-style functions that accept multiple parameters and iterate over them simultaneously.

And

```
lapply(names(lsD), function(X) {lsD$X<-cbind(lsD$X, lsV$X)})
```

will never work because you can't use variable names with the '$' operator. You can use

```
lapply(names(lsD), function(X) {lsD[[X]]<-cbind(lsD[[X]], lsV[[X]])})
```

Comment: Hi MrFlick! Thank you, that is simply beautiful! I haven't used `Map` before, but it does exactly what I need so i will read more into it! Very grateful!